# React App with React-Router-DOM: Link vs Achor Tag

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In a React app should we always be using the Link component provided by react-router-dom for creating links (both within the app and external links)? Are there situations where we should be using the HTML anchor tag directly?

Comment: Using `HTML anchor` tag triggers a page refresh when clicked while a `Link` component doesn't. As React is used to create Single Page Applications(SPA), it's more reasonable to use `Link`.

Comment: As an add for what @Major_Ash said, what is natively from React (even if link is based on anchor tag) is far better than vanilla HTML. More powerful and secure and is good to keep a logic in the code, using just one type of components

Comment: I don't think you fully understand how the `Link` component works. It renders an anchor tag into the DOM, so either way you are rendering an anchor tag. On top of that, the `Link` component only links to paths *within* your application, it can't link out to external resources, so you will need to use conventional anchor tags *anyway* for this to work. Typically you would open such external links in a new routing context (new tab/window/etc.) to avoid leaving your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React is commonly used to create single page application that removes the need for page refresh that could reset the app states. The anchor tag's **href** will trigger page reload wherein react-router-dom's **link/navlink** won't thus retaining states.

So if you want to navigate to relative URLs provided by React Router, use **link/navlink**, and anchor tags **href** should only be used for absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

The **href** attribute of anchor tag would trigger a page refresh which would reset the application states. However, the **Link** and **NavLink** of **react-router** doesn't trigger a page refresh.